# Body not expading with the content inside. Images and canvas overlapping the body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a resizable split view you can drag the line between to increase and decrease the size of the left and right screens. the right screen consists of two canvases containing 2 images on them we can write on that canvas. The problem is that the body has a height of 100% but the canvas overlapping the `<div class="container1">` and the HTML, body. HTML and body is not expanding with the canvas as shown in the below image:
[image]

Here is the image of the `<div class="container1">` border consisting of right and left sides and a resizable line between them. I can not resize below the container line because the container is not expanding with the canvas.
[image]
**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="container1">
      <div class="container__left">    
          <form id="orderByPicFrm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                type="hidden"
                class="form-control"
                id="code"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Code"
                size="3"
                disabled
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="itemName">Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="itemName"
                placeholder="Name"
                size="50"
              />
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="qty">clear </label>
              <button
                type="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                onclick="clearfield(event)"
              >
                clear
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>   
      </div>

      <div class="resizer" id="dragMe"></div>

      <div class="container__right">
        <div class="absolute">
          <div id="navbar">
            <button type="button" onclick="zoomin_canvas()">+</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="zoomout_canvas()">-</button>
            <button id="rotateRight" onclick="rotateRight()">Right</button>
            <button id="rotateLeft" onclick="rotateLeft()">Left</button>
            <button id="Button1" onclick="draw()">draw</button>
            <label> Marking</label>
            <label class="switch">
              <input type="checkbox" checked onclick="doMarking()" id="mark" />
              <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="fix">
            <img id="img1" src="img.JPG" style="display: none" />

            <canvas
              fileName="img.JPG"
              id="canvas1"
              rotate="0"
              onclick="selectImg(event)"
              onmousedown="mouseDown(event)"
              onmouseup="mouseUp(event)"
              onmousemove="mouseMove(event)"
            >
              Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
            </canvas>

            <img id="img2" src="img2.jpeg" style="display: none" />

            <canvas
              fileName="img2.jpeg"
              id="canvas2"
              rotate="0"
              onclick="selectImg(event)"
              onmousedown="mouseDown(event)"
              onmouseup="mouseUp(event)"
              onmousemove="mouseMove(event)"
            >
              Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
            </canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
     <style>
          .container1 {
            display: flex;
            border: 1px solid #cbd5e0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
          }
          .container__left {
            width: 50%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            min-width: 18rem;
          }
          .resizer {
            background-color: #cbd5e0;
            cursor: ew-resize;
            height: 100%;
            width: 2px;
          }
          .container__right {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
          }
body,
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

        </style>
```

I took the resizable code from this website :https://htmldom.dev/create-resizable-split-views/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are positioned absolutely even if the body has 100% width and height. Remove positioning and display the elements in flex.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left_panel {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: scroll;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  max-height: 70vh;
}
```